# iOS importing custom font difficulty

Tags: ios, fonts

I have done everything to get the following font working using a .ttf :

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Miso
...

I. Here they are in my project column:

[image]

II. Here they are in my plist file.

[image]

III ...and here now in my Copy Bundle Resources

[image]

Here is it's name according to the apple font program:

[image]

And here according to its CTRL + CLICK,  "get info"

[image]

All attempts to log it like so:

```
  NSLog(@"the font: %@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Miso Light"]);
NSLog(@"the font: %@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Miso-Light"]);
NSLog(@"the font: %@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Miso"]);
NSLog(@"the font: %@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Miso Light"]);


NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
{
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
    fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                 [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                  [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
    for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
    {
        NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
    }
```

... are proving fruitless. This is one man's wit's end to importing a custom font to iOS.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Miso Light" size:...]` ?

Comment: Thank you. It returns (NULL) instead of empty space.

Comment: So what *does* appear in the list of family names and font names you're printing at the end there?  Anything family name with the word "Marten" in it at all?